# Strncpy() string length output error

Tags: c, string, strncpy

I am having a problem with `strncpy()` copying an extra character at the length I need. I need to copy the 10 most significant bits from one string to another (both in `char*` format).

The size of the larger variable does not intuitively matter, and the smaller only affects the output when it is significantly smaller than the value I need (I don't know why this is either).

The n value in my `strncpy()` may be what's causing the problem, but I have no idea why it's acting the way it is. If I'm not mistaken, n, the length of the destination string, should be 1 longer than the data, to account for the null character at the end.

My string is not behaving this way at all. Setting `n` to `11`, I receive the following output:

```
00000111101100100100001110100000

00000111101
```

I would imagine it would only copy 10 characters, with the final one for the null. Increasing `n` produces the same results.

Decreasing n to 10 reveals the heart of the problem:

```
00000111101100100100001110100000

0000011110@
```

I don't know why it would do this, but it continues to do this as n decreases, until `n` is much smaller (around 8).

These are the relevant lines of my code:

```
char line[11], hexAddr[8], binAddr[33], lv1Index[11];
    ...
strncpy(lv1Index, binAddr, 10);
```

where `lv1Index` was untouched before this, and binAddr is displayed (in the given output) directly beforehand.

The added character is always `@`, so I don't believe it's garbage from `lv1Index` pre-initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [one C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/):

> If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it.
>
> No null-character is implicitly appended to the end of destination, so destination will only be null-terminated if the length of the C string in source is less than num.

Other documentation ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdsywd25.aspx), [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/)) has similar information.

This means you should put the null terminator on yourself:

```
 lv1Index[10] = '\0';
```

Comment: +1, Also, if he knows the original string is more than 10 characters long, he should use `memcpy` instead of `strncpy`

Comment: Ah, okay, well I still don't completely understand why everything was happening the way it was (why different values of n changed the output, seemingly unrelated to the size the destination), but this solves my problem. Thanks!